# Access autoloaded model from autoloaded library

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my autoload file I have several common libraries and several common model autoloaded:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','tools','common'....);
$autoload['model'] = array('mauth','madmin',...);
```

I'm in calling this code inside a library that calls another library:

```
class library1{
  function x(){
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->library2->y();
  }
}

class library2()
  function y(){
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $array_notifications = $this->CI->madmin->getNotifications();
  }
}
```

And I get:

```
Message: Undefined property: Splash::$madmin
```

I guess I may do this:

```
$this->CI->load->model('madmin');
```

But.. why? Why Can't I decide the load priority of my autoloaded classes?

Thanks

EDIT: Clarification

Comment: What do you mean with "I'm in common" ?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I explained better in the question, sorry and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no possibility of choosing the loading priority, and I think that hacking the core just to avoid writing a line is a bit...off.

I had to go search the core system to see better how things work. Looks like libraries are autoloaded before models, so you are right when saying that you need to load the model before calling one of its methods (I didn't tested though, but I think it works like this).

I don't know why is this done, but so far the only solution I see is to change yourself the order in which are loaded, but I warn you: I think that if things work this way there's a reason the CI developers has thought about; this might have drawbacks you cannot tell, so always be ready to a drawback in case you find problems.
This solution is just a bit speculative and not guaranteed, I'll appreciate your feedback as I cannot set up a testing environment right now to prove it

Go to the `system/core/loader.php` file, around line 1166 (the method is `_ci_autoloader()`) where the "libraries" index of `$autoload` array is checked, and swap its position with the 'model' index checking which is around line 1183.

And good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally think you should avoid autoloading as much as possible, since all resources will remain loaded whether you use them or not, as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600148/codeigniter-autoload).

Also, be aware that Model autoloading works somewhat differently than autoloading for other objects.

When working with models, CI assumes that any loaded library is also available within the model. So loading libraries **before** models is actually the right thing to do.